# Regex to to get 1 but not 11 in list.files R (with variables in the regex)

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to list files in a folder to perform an operation using the following code:

```
in.files <- list.files("../Monthly/", pattern=paste0("*",month,"_","\\b",year,".tif$"), full.names=TRUE)
```

`month` and `year` are variables coming from a data frame so I can eventually loop through the file list and do some raster operations.

The files are named:

```
site1_1_1985.tif
site1_11_1985.tif
site2_1_1985.tif
site2_11_1985.tif
```

etc.

The expected result for this when `month = 1` and `year = 1985`

```
site1_1_1985.tif
site2_1_1985.tif
```

But instead, I get

```
character(0)
```

I've tried removing `\\b`, but then I get all of the files back. I'm pretty new at regex, but any help I can get with this would be appreciated. I need to group all of the files by month and year as I'm trying to put data from different sites together.

Comment: try `paste0(".*_",month,"_",year,".tif$")`

Comment: The `_\b` pattern means that after `_` there can't be any letter, digit or `_`, but `year` does consist of digits - hence, no match. Remove `\b`. Add `_` before `month`. And remove `"*"` from the pattern, or replace with `.*`

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. That worked perfectly. Why does the ``.*_`` work?

Comment: this is a good site to play with regex https://regexr.com/